# how to create a jsfiddle using leaflet

Tags: leaflet, jsfiddle

I am struggling with jsfiddle trying to create a running example which uses leaflet.

because I was not successful I searched for some examples and found the following one working:

- http://jsfiddle.net/kedar2a/LnzN2/2/

I then copied the example in a new fiddle

- https://jsfiddle.net/aLn3ut5z/1/

but it is still not working...

when inserting the external resources, there was the following error:

> **jsfiddle.net says:**
>
> You're loading resources over HTTP not HTTPS, your fiddle will not
>   work. Do you wish to continue?

any suggestions what is wrong here?

p.s.: below is the code of the jsfiddle windows:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="map"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#map {
    height: 500px;
    width: 80%;
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
// We’ll add a tile layer to add to our map, in this case it’s a OSM tile layer.
// Creating a tile layer usually involves setting the URL template for the tile images
var osmUrl = 'http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
      osmAttrib = '&copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
      osm = L.tileLayer(osmUrl, {
        maxZoom: 18,
        attribution: osmAttrib
      });
// initialize the map on the "map" div with a given center and zoom
var map = L.map('map').setView([19.04469, 72.9258], 12).addLayer(osm);

// Script for adding marker on map click
function onMapClick(e) {
var marker = L.marker(e.latlng, {
    draggable: true,
    title: "Resource location",
    alt: "Resource Location",
    riseOnHover: true
    }).addTo(map)
    .bindPopup(e.latlng.toString()).openPopup();

    // Update marker on changing it's position
    marker.on("dragend", function(ev) {

    var chagedPos = ev.target.getLatLng();
    this.bindPopup(chagedPos.toString()).openPopup();

    });
    }
    map.on('click', onMapClick);
```

Comment: Note that you can simply load JSFiddle through `http` instead of `https`, like in your first link.

Comment: good catch! did not notice that! thanks! indeed it makes sense to do that in case there are no https repositories available!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The Leaflet CDN doesn't support SSL](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/1824) yet. You can use something not requiring https, like [playground-leaflet](http://playground-leaflet.rhcloud.com/) which is just a fork of JSBin with leaflet libraries easily selectable.

Alternatively, you could use [Leaflet from cdnjs.net](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/leaflet), which does support https.